# Need workaround for starting sound services

Tags: windows-7, safe-mode

Hello im looking for a workaround to enable the sound drivers in safemode. 
im using safemode for normal use because starting normally jams programs and causes alot of problems. + if there is a way to enable the opengl drivers in safemode to please tell me. its not important im just asking for a way to start the opengl drivers.

Update: Heres the problem with normal start it starts normally but when i log in everything goes nuts: freezing programs,leaving boxes,programs cant be switched to from taskbar, google chrome cant use internet,crashing explorer.exe, and all other sorts of problems.
it happend yesterday when a transformer blew and my computer shut down because of power loss.
i dont think anything got fried, so this is the reason why im using safemode for normal use

Comment: Why don't you just figure out the reason for your actual problem instead of trying to modify safe mode which by default does not load display drivers for a very good reason.  **Without the display drivers you won't be able to have OpenGL functionality.**

Comment: Safe Mode wasn't designed to be used for normal use. Please update your question with more specific details of the problems you're facing (e.g. exact error messages, what you mean by "leaving boxes", Google Chrome's error message when it can't access the Internet, etc.). Alternatively, you might want to ask a new question, but from your latest edit, it looks like your computer has a malware infection. [This might help](http://malwaretips.com/blogs/malware-removal-guide-for-windows/).

Comment: @Vinayak leaving boxes like right click boxes and the action center box stays up and the error for google chrome is "This webpage is not available"

Comment: @Vinayak But the question is what malware do i have

Comment: @craftxbox: When Google Chrome gives you a "This webpage is not available" error, it also includes a "More" button at the bottom. Click that and you'll see a detailed explanation of the problem. Add that to your question.

Comment: @Vinayak I dont exactly remember but it said something about the page taking too long to load

Comment: @craftxbox: I still don't understand what you mean by "right click boxes" or "action center box". A screenshot might help here. Also you don't need to know what malware you have. The malware scanner will do that for you and find and remove all (well, most) malicious software (if there are any).

Comment: @Vinayak the boxes where you select an action when you right click.
And i have AVG and im trying to get the command line scanner to work

Comment: [Extended discussions in comments](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2225/what-is-an-extended-discussion) is frowned upon on the StackExchange network. Please [follow the instructions on this page](http://malwaretips.com/blogs/malware-removal-guide-for-windows/) and if that hasn't solved your problem, ask a new question with the relevant details.

Comment: @Ramhound What Reason

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you fully understand what Safe Mode is for. Please read [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_mode#Operating_system_safe_mode).

Here's what Wikipedia has to say:

> Though it varies by operating system, typically **safe mode loads as few
>   executable modules as possible and usually disables devices, except
>   for the minimum necessary to display information and accept input**.
>   Safe mode can also take the form of a parallel "miniature" operating
>   system that has no configuration information shared with the normal
>   operating system. For example, on Microsoft Windows, the user can also
>   choose to boot to the Recovery Console, a small text-based
>   troubleshooting mode kept separate from the main operating system (and
>   can also be accessed by booting the install CD), or to various "safe
>   mode" options that run the dysfunctional OS, **but with features such as
>   video drivers, audio and networking disabled.**

Comment: I know but read the post again:                                       "im using safemode for normal use because starting normally jams programs and causes alot of problems."

Comment: Safe mode is not a proper answer for your problems. Have you actually understood what @Vinayk posted?

Comment: I still maintain that you should read the article on Safe Mode so you know what it is and why what you're asking is precisely what Safe Mode was designed to prevent.

Comment: This answer is completed and actually does provide a solution.  There are various minimal boot configurations that can solve the author's problem besides `safe mode`

Comment: I understand what safe mode is for. and the article @Vinayak posted

Answer (score 1):

Like most users here I will encourage you to use save mode to figure out what the issue is in the normal start up.  You will not have full functionality in safe mode.  If you want your computer to perform like it should use safe mode for its intended purpose, to figure out what is the issue with the normal system.  Remove all unnecessary devices.